# How do I get a new command line to appear in terminal

Tags: terminal, prompt

What is the keyboard shortcut for getting another prompt

```
ari@ari-virutal-machine:
```

to appear:
[image]

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, are you perhaps looking for a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` or `screen`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no keyboard shortcut that will make a new prompt appear in the terminal. A new prompt will be automatically generated when processing of the previous command entered in the terminal (here, the `node` program) has finished. So, everything that does "create" a new prompt will interfere in the running of the previously launched program.

In your case, it would seem that you have started a server that is now listening to incoming connections. As such, it will not terminate on its own unless instructed so by (depending on the exact service) a remote command, or by killing it manually from another console.

If you don't want a command to "block" your console, you could start the command in the background by appending a `&`, as in

```
node test_file.js &
```

You can achieve the same "retroactively" by pressing (in the console where you started the program) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> - which will *pause the command you launched*, thereby returning control to you - and then typing

```
bg
```

which will resume it in the "background".

Since you are working in a graphical environment, you could also open a new terminal window and just let this one run.

If everything else fails, you could type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal window to forcibly kill the process you started, which will return control to you (but the program you started will then be gone).

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be running a command.  The prompt will re-appear when control has been given back to the shell.  This will happen when the command (`node`) has terminated.  You may probably terminate it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> (which will send an interrupt signal to the running process).  Whether this will work depends on the code that you are running.